# ImageView cannot be centered in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, imageview, fragment, android-relativelayout

I've already tried adding `layout_gravity, and gravity, and centerInParent`.. but the image view still shows up at the left upper corner of the screen..Am I missing something?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/noHistroySign"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/sign"
        />
    ....
```

Comment: just set gravity of RelativeLayout as center. That should work.

Comment: Can you show us *all* of the .xml layout? There seems to be something going on outside of these two views and there isn't enough context to figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your layout. Your `ImageView` is already in center. Its correct.

I think there is a problem in `android:background="@drawable/sign"` perhaps sign image is not displaying correctly or not found or not in drawable folder.

Try to change different image and other image will be in center perfectly.

Comment: You're right. That's weird though, because it works on a phone.
The problem started when I made a copy of that layout to address Tablet sized screens.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your imageview

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.. It's still in the upper left corner.
Thank you.

Comment: remove these three codes   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 0):

In RelativeLayout using below property we centered *ImageView* or other child view.Just add below line in *ImageView* property.

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
```

and write

```
    android:src="@drawable/sign"
```

inplace of

```
    android:background="@drawable/sign"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sign" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sign" />

</RelativeLayout>
```